# > Let $A=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb R^2|x^2+y^2\ge 1\}\cup\{(0,0)\}$, and let $d$ be a usual metric on $A$. Find the closure of $B_d((0,0),1)$

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

> Let $A=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb R^2|x^2+y^2\ge 1\}\cup\{(0,0)\}$, and let
>   $d$ be a usual metric on $A$. Find the closure of $B_d((0,0),1)$and
>   int$\{(0,0)\}$. prove your result.

[image]

$B_d((0,0),1)=\{(x,y)\in A:x^2+y^2<1\}=\{(0,0)\}$
Case1:- Any neighbourhood of $(0,0)$ intersects $\{(0,0)\}$. So, $(0,0)\in \overline{B_d((0,0),1)}$. $x$ can not use for inspection. Since $x\notin A$.
$B_d(y,.5)\cap \{(0,0)\}=\phi$.So, $y \notin \overline{B_d((0,0),1)}$.  similarly $B_d(z,.5)\cap \{(0,0)\}=\phi$. Hence $\{0,0\}$ is the only limit point. int$\{(0,0)\}=\{0,0\}$. Since, $B_d((0,0),.5)\subset \{(0,0)\}$. Am I right?

Comment: I don't follow your case-by-case argument. What is case 1? Is there a case 2? What does "$x$ can not use for inspection" mean?

Comment: I mean in case 1. Arbitrary pint inside the open unit disk other than $(0,0)$ is the pint in the closure of $\{(0,0)\}$. Case2. Points in the unit circle won't lie in the closure of  $\{(0,0)\}$. Case 3 points outside closed disk. won't be in the closure.

Answer (score 1):

As @William Elliot points out, in any metric space points are closed.

Note that $B_d((0,0),1)=\{(0,0)\}\subset A$.

So you are taking the closure of a closed set (consisting of one point).

Conclusion?..

Secondly,  since you have proved $p=(0,0)$ is open,  use the fact that the interior is the largest open set contained in the set of interest. Or, the interior of an open set is the set itself.

Answer (score 0):

Other than showing {(0,0)} is open,
you've accomplished nothing.

Exercise.  Prove for all p in a
metric space, that {p} is closed.

With that you're basically done.

Comment: I mean in case 1. Arbitrary point inside the open unit disk other than $(0,0)$ is the point not in the closure of $\{(0,0)\}$. Case2. Points in the unit circle won't lie in the closure of  $\{(0,0)\}$. Case 3 points outside closed disk. won't be in the closure.

Comment: Within A, the only point not on the circle is {(0,1)}.  Do the exercise.

Comment: Am I correct? Can you tell me?

Comment: Why I am asking this questions, because I lack confidence :(.

Comment: You showed every point but p is not a limit point.  You also need to show that p is not a limit point.  Teaching limit points is mostly nonsense.  You showed that every point is not an adherance point.  That would suffice to show {p} is closed, but no, they teach this silly limit point thing so you have to additionally show p is not a limit point.

Comment: @Mathgeek p in {p} subset closure {p}.

Comment: sorry again typo. My intention was to say $y\neq p$ is not in the $\overline{ \{p\}}$